# Why are some singular masculine attributive adjectives treated like that?

Tags: adjetivos, género, número-gramatical

All adjectives are either attributive or predicative. Predicative adjectives usually have four forms: singular feminine ending in "-a"; plural feminine ending in "-as"; singular masculine ending in "-o"; plural masculine ending in "-os".

However, I have noticed in some singular masculine attributive adjectives, for example "bueno" simplifies to "buen". So as a predicative adjective, we say "El té es muy bueno". But as an attributive adjective, we say "El precio es un muy buen valor".

Why is this practice followed in some singular masculine attributive adjectives?

Comment: Some adjectives in Spanish change their form based on their position: un buen hombre but un hombre bueno. The same is true of buen valor and valor bueno.  Or in this feminine one: noticia mala and mala noticia. They all mean the same thing before or after in these particular cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are *apocopic forms*; [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_adjectives#Apocope) tells you which adjectives have that but not *why* they are treated like that. The same is true for *uno* (a numeral/article, not an adjective) which gets shortened to *un* before masculine nouns.

Such a phenomenon [occurs quite often](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) in languages; I'm not a linguist but as far as I know, there's nothing special about these cases. Perhaps the only word that changes meaning this way is [gran/grande](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_adjectives#Words_that_change_meaning).

Answer (score 1):

*Notas previas y Generales para el caso y que usted lo entienda*;

- Atributivo - El adjetivo se encuentra delante del sustantivo.

The big house - La gran casa (forma corta, "gran")

- Predicativo - El adjetivo va detrás del sustantivo.

The house is big - La casa es grande (forma larga, "grande")

---

Antes de entrar en materia, debe de saber en línea generales;

- Lo que usted llama adjetivos atributivos y predicativos de forma general, en Español especificamos como un grupo de adjetivos particular, no muy numeroso, que presentan "apócope", es decir, una forma recortada, (grande, gran) y que se utiliza cuando van delante de un sustantivo o nombre masculino singular (buen, mal...). Por tanto, a la hora de utilizarlos es importante tener en cuenta la posición que ocupan estos adjetivos en la oración, si se encuentran delante o detrás del nombre y así determinar un correcto uso de sus dos formas.
- Aunque la mayor parte de los adjetivos se utilizan indistintamente en función atributiva o predicativa, este pequeño grupo de adjetivos (bueno, malo, grande....) tienen sus propias características y depende de si van delante o detrás del nombre para utilizar en ese caso una forma completa u otra más corta (forma larga, forma corta).

Ejemplos de comprensión general antes de continuar, ver excepciones y las formas en femenino.
Comprender que;

- **El niño bueno**, el adjetivo "bueno" va detrás del nombre "niño", y así se utiliza la forma larga del adjetivo "bueno". "El niño bueno".
- **El buen niño**, el adjetivo "bueno" va delante del nombre "niño", por eso se utiliza la forma de apócope o recortada de "buen" (forma corta). "El buen niño".

---

**Apócope**

---

Apócope (del griego apokopé < apokopto, "cortar") es una figura en la que se produce una pérdida o desaparición de uno o varios fonemas o sílabas al final de algunas palabras.

---

- Apócope de Adjetivos.
- Gran / Grande.
- Los números.
- San o Santo.
- Buen o Bueno.
- Cualquier o Cualquiera.
- Apócope del Adverbio.

---

En Español moderno existen unos pocos adjetivos que presentan apócope ( *pérdida o desaparición de uno o varios fonemas o sílabas*) ante un sustantivo masculino singular cuando se anteponen al nombre, de esta forma se suele hablar, coloquialmente, que estas palabras tienen dos formas, una forma larga y otra corta. "bueno o buen / malo o mal..."

La forma larga (bueno, malo) se utiliza cuando van detrás de un nombre o están solos, mientras que la forma corta (buen, mal), se aplica cuando van delante de un nombre.

La mayoría de estos adjetivos, cuando van delante de un nombre masculino singular solo usan la forma más corta. En todos los casos pierden la "o" final, sin embargo, las formas femeninas y los plurales no cambian.

- *Con un nombre "femenino", hay entonces que tener presente que no hay forma corta*.
- "Es una buena niña". (forma larga)
- "Es una niña buena". (forma larga)
- "Es una mala profesora" (forma larga)
- "Es una profesora mala" (forma larga)

---

Este fenómeno gramático recibe el nombre de "**Apócope**", y trata de la supresión de sonidos al final o en posición final de ciertas palabras.

Ejemplos

- Quiero un gato, no dos.
- ¡Qué tengas un buen día! Ahora es un mal momento para ir.

Otros ejemplos de Apócope

Como se puede ver en los siguientes ejemplos, las palabras que van seguidas de un apócope son masculinas.

---

- Uno   /     Un    /     Quiero un peluche, no dos.
- Bueno  /     Buen /     ¡ Qué tengas un buen día!
- Malo  /      Mal  /     Ahora es un mal momento para ir a Santiago.
- Primero /    Primer /   Es el primer capítulo de la novela.
- Tercero /    Tercer /   Miércoles es el tercer día de la semana.
- Alguno /     Algún  /  ¿Habrá algún señor amable que me de dos euros?
- Ninguno     Ningún  /   No tengo ningún libro en la casa.

Habitualmente los adjetivos "apócope" que acaban en "o" pierden la "o" final cuando van delante de un sustantivo masculino singular.

---

**Gran o Grande**

Cuando Grande significa que "alguien o algo es importante, sobresaliente o notable" se apocopa "gran" si va delante de un sustantivo masculino o femenino singular.

- Él es un gran atleta.
- Vivo en una gran ciudad.
- Algún día podrás ser un gran cómico.
- Fue una gran noticia, me alegre mucho.

Cuándo "*Grande*" se refiere al tamaño de algo, normalmente va después del sustantivo:

- Vivo en una ciudad grande.
- Tengo un perro grande.

**Nota**: *No se apocopa "grande" cuando es parte de un comparativo*.

Ella es una tenista importantísima. Es la más grande de todos los tiempos.

**Diferencia entre "Un hombre grande" y "Un gran hombre"**

- Al decir, "Un hombre grande", nos referimos a su estatura, tamaño y aquellos aspectos de su constitución física en general.
- En cambio, si decimos, "Un gran hombre" estamos aludiendo a la forma de ser, con las características notables y positivas de ser un buen ser humano.

---

**Los Números**

Número       Apócope               Ejemplo

Uno          Un                    Quiero un vaso de jugo por favor
Ciento       Cien                  Ni en cien años te perdonaré.
Primero      Primer                Ese fue su primer beso.
Tercero      Tercer                Vive en el tercer piso.

*El número 100 (cien) también se apocopa antes de un sustantivo, un adjetivo y los numerales mil, millón, billón*.

Ejem.

- Un siglo tiene cien años.
- Tengo que leer cien fichas para el examen.

Sin embargo, decimos *ciento* cuarenta (140), *ciento* tres (103), *ciento* treinta (130), etc.

---

**San o Santo**

Normalmente *Santo* se apocopa a *San* antes de los sustantivos propios masculinos (nombres) de los Santos:

Ejemplos

- San Pedro es el patrono de los pescadores.
- Hoy es el día de San Blas.

*Se exceptúan los nombres de Santo que comienzan con Do- o To-*

Santo Domingo, Santo Toribio, Santo Tomás, Santo Tobías.

Cuando existe artículo es *El Santo Miguel*.

---

**Buen o Bueno**

Los Adjetivos "bueno y malo" se acortan en "buen y mal" delante de un sustantivo singular masculino.

Ejemplos

- Es un buen día para pescar. (forma corta)
- Tengo un mal presentimiento. (forma corta)
- "Es un buen niño". (forma corta)
- "Es un mal profesor"  (forma corta)

Los Adjetivos "bueno y malo" se alargan cuando van detrás de un sustantivo singular masculino.

- "Es un niño bueno". (forma larga)
- "Es un profesor malo" (forma larga)

---

**Cualquier o Cualquiera**

Cualquiera es acortado delante de un sustantivo singular masculino.

Delante de un sustantivo singular femenino se puede usar tanto "Cualquier" como "Cualquiera".

Ejemplos

- Cualquier persona es capaz de hacer eso.
- Cualquier niño puede jugar a eso.

---

**Apócope del adverbio**

Con los adverbios: *tanto*, *cuánto*, *mucho* y *recientemente* se acortan cuando preceden a un adjetivo, a otro adverbio o una frase preposicional:

Adverbio      Apócope        Ejemplo

- tanto  /       tan      -       Es tan ordenado con sus cosas.
- cuánto    /    cuán     -   ¡Cuán feliz estoy con tu nuevo trabajo!
- mucho   /      muy      -     Ahora está muy de moda la comida India.
- recientemente /  recién   -     Mi camisa está recién lavada.

---

---

---

Video

Aprender español: ¿Bueno o buen? ¿Grande o gran? (nivel básico)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1Oj14tYLyw&feature=emb_imp_woyt

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special with those adjectives, neither is there a "rule" to identify them (apart from memorizing a list).

This occurs also in another languages, as a part of their adaptation though time.